# How to graph a function based on a String on Android

Tags: java, android, function, dynamic, graph

This is a question I've asked myself since I began programming again and again.

My goal:

1. draw a function graph based on a string like "sin(x-1)*2.5" FAST.
2. fast means fast enough to be fun
3. it must run on Android

What I tried:

1. using my own very simple parser (slow and primitive)
2. using the JavaScript parser (slow but flexible)
3. using the [Janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home) runtime compiler (fast and flexible, perfect, but only for normal Java)

I've googled extensively (queries like "android function graph how to"), but not found a solution,
although there are numerous applications managing to do this.

I will not accept "write your own parser/compiler" :)

SO: How do I do this?

Thank you very much in advance,

Till Höppner

Comment: I'm not 100% sure whether ``exp4j`` is Android compatible but might be worth trying out;  http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/

Comment: maybe something like http://jeval.sourceforge.net/ could work too.

Comment: http://php.sabscape.com/blog/?p=440

Comment: I gave up trying parsers at the JavaScript Parser, how comes it was so slow, compared to those you mentioned? These look good, I'll try them right away :D

Comment: So, I tried [expr](https://github.com/darius/expr/tree/master/expr) which gives a NullpointerException when starting a 5 line program, and with [exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/index.html) I get a VerifyError... at constructNative

Comment: How stupid to assume I could include .CLASS libraries into an Android project with .DEX files... With sourcecode it might work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of harism and John Boker,
I achieved my goal quite easily.

---

My conclusions:

- **DO NOT** put **.CLASS** libraries in your Android project, because these have **.DEX** files
- Use either the [**dx**](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/compiler-android-dx-compiler.html) tool, on those libraries, or use the **source code** of them
- [**expr**](https://github.com/darius/expr/tree/master/expr) runs fastest in my app

---

Thank you, harism and John Boker

EDIT: This is nonsense, I don't know why I thought this...